# Getting source of iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a file `x.xhtml` and another file `main.html`, in which I am using `<iframe src=x.xhtml id=childframe>`. Now what I want to do is, after the file is loaded, I want to get the source of the child frame, i.e `x.xhtml`, using JavaScript.

I tried the following code

```
function getChildInput() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('childFrame').contentWindow; 
    var childText = iframe.document.getElementById('childText'); 
    alert(iframe.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);   
}
```

but it didn't work for `.xhtml`. If I am using `.html` instead, it works fine.

Is this a problem with XHTML or is there any other way of getting the source from the child frame other than HTML?

Comment: Is the extension the only difference?

Comment: yes! extension is the only difference when i am changing the same file to x.html with works fine

Comment: Have a look at the console which error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try `alert(iframe.document.body.innerHTML);`
or

```
var doc_iframe = document.getElementsByName("myFrame")[0].contentWindow.document;
```

HTH

Ivo Stoykov

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement) property:

```
alert(iframe.document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Can you give us the `Content-Type` header of the server response for the iframe, using a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)? Assuming your iframe actually contains something, and is served from the same domain as your main page, there might be something wrong there.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi i am using firefox , moreover when i try to open the file in internet explorer its pops out download box seems IE dosent handle xml files

Comment: @imran, if the web server is under your control, try to serve `.xhtml` files as `text/xml` instead. That will solve IE's "download box" problem and might help in Firefox.

Comment: @^^ thanks i got the problem solved var iframe = document.getElementById('childFrame').contentDocument; 
//var childText = iframe.document.getElementById('childText');

alert(iframe.documentElement.textContent);

Comment: @imran, glad to hear that :) Please consider updating your question with your solution, or maybe replying with your own answer, so future readers can easily find it.